# How to display results from selected radio buttons into one textbox using a for loop?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, radio-button, server-side

I am making a html form and when the user submits the form an `aspx` page will load to display the results of the form. I have 20 questions total with 5 radio buttons each. For some reason when I try to retrieve the selected radio buttons thru a for loop, it only displays one answer. What am I doing wrong?

I have tried changing the values in the for loop but it just seems to not be displaying correctly.

Here's the code for the aspx.cs

```
public void DisplayResults(double[] results)
    {
        try
        {  
            int q = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i <= 19; i++)
            {
                if (i == 0)
                {
                    txtResults.Text = "Course Results";
                    if (results[i] == 1)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Disagree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 2)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Disagree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 3)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Neutral";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 4)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Agree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 5)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Agree ZERO";
                    }
                }
                else if (i == 11)
                {
                    txtResults.Text = "Professor Results";
                    if (results[i] == 1)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Disagree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 2)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Disagree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 3)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Neutral";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 4)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Agree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 5)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Agree ELEVEN";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (results[i] == 1)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Disagree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 2)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Disagree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 3)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Neutral";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 4)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Agree";
                    }
                    else if (results[i] == 5)
                    {
                        txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Agree ELSE";

                    }
                }
                if (txtResults.Text == "")
                {
                    throw new Exception();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.Write(e.Message, "Error");
        }
    }
```

Here's the code for aspx

```
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Feedback Results</legend>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtResults" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="100%" Height="500px"></asp:TextBox>
        </fieldset>
```

Here's my html code

```
<h3>Please answer these questions to the best of your knowledge:</h3>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Course Content (Organization, Clarity of Expectations/Directions, Balance/Appropriateness)</legend>
            1. The course (or section) presented skills in a helpful sequence
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q1" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            2. The course (or section) provided an appropriate balance between instruction and practice
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q2" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            3. The course (or section) was appropriate for the stated level of the class
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q3" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            4. The course (or section) was organized in a way that helped me learn
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q4" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            5. The lab helped to complement the lectures
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q5" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            6. The course (or section) provided a mixture of explanation and practice
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q6" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q6" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q6" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q6" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q6" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            7. The course (or section) was effectively organized
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q7" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q7" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q7" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q7" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q7" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            8. The course (or section) assignments and lectures usefully complemented each other
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q8" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q8" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q8" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q8" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q8" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            9. The course (or section) instructions (including, manuals, handouts, etc.) were clear
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q9" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q9" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q9" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q9" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q9" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            10. The course (or section) work helped me understand concepts more clearly
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q10" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q10" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q10" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q10" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q10" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            11. Instructions for course (or section) materials (including manuals, handouts, etc.) were clear
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q11" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q11" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q11" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q11" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q11" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            12. The lab complemented my understanding of the lectures
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q12" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q12" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q12" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q12" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q12" value="1" />strongly disagree
        </fieldset>
        <br />
        <br />

        <fieldset>
            <legend> Instructor Specific Questions</legend>
            1. The instructor clearly presented the skills to be learned
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q13" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q13" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q13" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q13" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q13" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            2. The instructor effectively presented concepts and techniques
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q14" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q14" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q14" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q14" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q14" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            3. The instructor presented content in an organized manner
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q15" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q15" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q15" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q15" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q15" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            4. The instructor effectively presented the tools (e.g. materials, skills, and techniques) needed
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q16" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q16" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q16" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q16" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q16" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            5. The instructor explained concepts clearly
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q17" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q17" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q17" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q17" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q17" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            6. The instructor made the elements of good writing clear
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q18" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q18" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q18" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q18" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q18" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            7. The instructor clearly articulated the standards of performance for the course
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q19" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q19" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q19" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q19" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q19" value="1" />strongly disagree
            <br />
            <br />
            8. The instructor provided guidance for understanding course exercises
            <br />
            <input type="radio" name="q20" value="5" />strongly agree
            <input type="radio" name="q20" value="4" />agree
            <input type="radio" name="q20" value="3" />neutral
            <input type="radio" name="q20" value="2" />disagree
            <input type="radio" name="q20" value="1" />strongly disagree
        </fieldset>
```

I want to be able to display each result for each question in the same multi-line textbox like so but it be split between courses and professor questions:

**COURSES**

Q1: Disagree

Q2: Neutral

Q3: Neutral

etc...

**PROFESSOR**

Q1: Disagree

Q2: Neutral

Q3: Neutral

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: It's because you've not incremented the q value,

> Incorrect because q is always 1:

```
txtResults.Text = "Course Results";
if (results[i] == 1)
{
    txtResults.Text += "Q" + q + ": Strongly Disagree";
}
```

Second, you've allowed the program to write for cases where i=0 and i=11

Full answer:

```
public void DisplayResults(double[] results)
{
    try
    {  
        for (int i = 0, q = 1; i <= 19; i++, q++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
                txtResults.Text += "Course Results";
            }
            if (i == 11)
            {
                txtResults.Text += "Professor Results";
            }
            txtResults.Text += "Q" + q ": ";
            if (results[i] == 1)
            {
                txtResults.Text +="Strongly Disagree";
            }
            else if (results[i] == 2)
            {
                txtResults.Text +="Disagree";
            }
            else if (results[i] == 3)
            {
                txtResults.Text +=": Neutral";
            }
            else if (results[i] == 4)
            {
                txtResults.Text +="Agree";
            }
            else if (results[i] == 5)
            {
                if(i == 0 )
                txtResults.Text +="Strongly Agree ZERO";
                else if(i == 11 )
                txtResults.Text +="Strongly Agree ELEVEN";
                else
                txtResults.Text +="Strongly Agree";
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.Write(e.Message, "Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: it still gives me the same results

Comment: there is one more mistake you have made, I'll update my answer now

Comment: If `i` is zero, it will try to find Q0 which does not exist?

Comment: @JasonAller The OP is just displaying the result as `Q0: Agree, Q1: Disagree`, not manipulating it... btw thanks for letting me know, I'll update the answer

Comment: An improvement might be to use an array of objects to hold (question type, value, text response) and then the repeated if statements could be done with a lookup based on question type and value to get the text response.